# Adding number of time steps at the end/start of a zoo time series

Tags: r, zoo

I have a zoo time series and I want to add some dummy time steps with same time interval at the end/start. For example, I have the following time series and I want to add two more time steps at the end, for times `......21:00:00 BST` and  `......21:30:00 BST`  where all observations are zero.

```
my.zoo.ts = zoo(matrix(c(1:8),ncol=2),
            c("2012-07-05 19:00:00 BST", "2012-07-05 19:30:00 BST", 
              "2012-07-05 20:00:00 BST", "2012-07-05 20:30:00 BST"))
```

What is the easiest way to do it? (Apart from editing the above code, Of course) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series is currently using character strings for times which is not likely what you want so first convert them to POSIXct date/time objects:

```
time(my.zoo.ts) <- as.POSIXct(time(my.zoo.ts))
```

The times seem to be spaced by 30 minutes so suppose we want to append 100 and 101 in the two columns at 30 minutes past the last time:

```
z <- zoo(cbind(100, 101), end(my.zoo.ts) + 30 * 60)
rbind(my.zoo.ts, z)
```

Comment: Many thanks. I wouldn't have found out this on my own.